# Can't access TextBox inside Repeater Itemtemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

**I know this question is asked already for a couple of times but i didn't get the solution..**

i have tried this below code:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in repeater1.Items)
        {
            TextBox txtName = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtComment");
            if (txtName != null)
            {
                lblCheck.Text= txtName.Text;
            }
        }
```

the above code works but return empty...

this code finds the TextBox txtComment really well i mean when i have debug this code the value i entered in the txtComment TextBox assigned to lblCheck Label but than the lblCheck where i'm showing the TextBox value is disappeared don't know whats happened to that Label...

than i search about this problem than someone said that use
EnableViewState="False" in the repeater but when i put this attribute
now the whole repeater is disappeared....

This is aspx page

```
  <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater1" EnableViewState="false">
     <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="Postcomment" style="float:left;background-         color:yellow;padding:5px;width:100%;margin-top:10px">
                    <div style="float:left;background-   color:AppWorkspace;width:100%">

                        <div style="float:left;width:100%">
                            <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#   "Images\\"+Eval("userPic") %>' Width="24" Height="24" />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtComment"    placeholder="write a comment..." style="margin-top:2.5px;margin-  left:5px;width:92%"></asp:TextBox>

                        </div>
                        <div style="float:right">

                            <input type="button" value="Post"   id="btnComment" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

</ItemTemplate>
```

so please help me, i'm facing this problem in my final year project so i must have to solved this...

thanks

Comment: can you put your aspx code?

Comment: I'm guessing one of your txtComment is empty. Try to change your code lblCheck.Text= txtName.Text; to lblCheck.Text= string.Format("Comment: {0}", txtName.Text); If you had able to see the Comment: then it means one of your txtComment contains empty string.

Comment: not working..... just shows Comment:

Comment: it means its working. is just that one of your textComment had empty string. try this 
                if (txtName != null && txtName.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
                {
                    lblCheck.Text= txtName.Text;
                }

Answer (score 0):

You need to check Item Type of the Repeater Item. Try out this:

```
  foreach (RepeaterItem item in repeater1.Items)
       {             
      if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
         {
               TextBox txtName = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtComment");
                if (txtName != null)
                {
                    lblCheck.Text= txtName.Text;
                }
          }
       }
```

Comment: how did you bind your repeater?

Comment: if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                DataTable dt = Helper.ExecutePlainQuery("select * from post inner join userregistration on post.uid=userregistration.uid inner join profile on userregistration.uid=profile.uid order by postid DESC");
                repeater1.DataSource = dt;
                repeater1.DataBind();      }

Comment: Looks perfect check your TextBox have value or not ??